# Meta Stack Overflow Stickers are Here!

Tags: discussion, stickers

As requested in [We need a Meta sticker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/we-need-a-meta-sticker)

[image: sticker]

Which [reminds me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079367/quotes)..

> Navin R. Johnson: The new phone book's here! The new phone book's here!
>
> Harry Hartounian: Boy, I wish I could get that excited about nothing.
>
> Navin R. Johnson: Nothing? Are you kidding? Page 73 - Johnson, Navin R.! I'm somebody now! Millions of people look at this book everyday! This is the kind of spontaneous publicity - your name in print - that makes people. I'm in print! Things are going to start happening to me now.
>
> [the Sniper points to Navin's name in the phone book]
>
> Sniper: Johnson, Navin R... sounds like a typical b*****d.

These are technically limited edition stickers, only 50 were made. Michael Pryor is getting the first one. And of course our 4 dedicated Meta moderators will be getting them!

Reminder: **any user from [the first page of /users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) can request one by mailing your postal mail address to the email address at the bottom of every page.**

Comment: Needs more navel gazing.

Comment: Is an international address acceptable? :( (In this case Canada)

Comment: yes international addresses are acceptable, *IF* you are on the first page of /users.

Comment: I assume at the time of sending the e-mail? :)

Comment: That looks like a placemat to me. awesome.

Comment: Awesome.  The rarity alone should make these a highly-sought-after prize.  Thanks for making them.

Comment: Super exciting!! *Stares at navel*

Comment: All I need is this sticker.  That's all I need. And an SO T-shirt.  The sticker and an SO T-shirt and that's all I need. And a window cling for the car.  The sticker, the T-shirt, and the window cling, and that's all I need...

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - +1 for my *favorite* scene. Classic.

Comment: + w00t! w00t! do you international mail? :)

Comment: w00t w00t read the comments.

Comment: I didn't realize I was on the first page.

Comment: Am I too late to get my sticker?

Comment: Aw man, I am 8 spots away from the front page....

Answer (score 5):

> Beyond that, any user from the first page of /users can request one by mailing your postal mail address to the email address at the bottom of every page.

Endless navel-gazing and talking about others asking questions and answers finally has its rewards!

Answer (score 2):

Please don't make the package any fancy. The or Icelandic toll service will get jealous and make me pay strange fees and have to explain the package.

(I once had to come down to the office and explain what on earth [this](http://the.taoofmac.com/media/Hardware/Nostromo%20N50%20SpeedPad/Image1.jpg) was)

Comment: That looks like a Powerglove for keyboards.

Comment: it's meta. the color scheme is gray and blood red. you were expecting FANCY?

Comment: The package. Not the actual item.

Comment: Envelopes are fancy in Iceland. Make sure you wrap the stickers in bits of soiled and tattered clothing you take off your slaves (you **do** have slaves to make your waffles, right?) and use a bare minimum of twine to hold it together. The Icelandic people will all steal the bits of twine and soiled cloth, but they will not take the stickers for fear they were created by the devil.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage - OMG, that looks like something you would use to control the Omnidroids from "The Incredibles". *"It's bigger. It's badder. Ladies and gentlemen, it's too much for Mr. Incredible!"*

Answer (score 1):

Why the oval-shape, rather than the cut-out shape like the others?

Comment: I think it's because they're a standard sticker rather than a custom job

Comment: It's cheaper that way.

Comment: Let's hope there's enough interest in these to prompt Jeff to make more in the future with Websticker.

Answer (score 1):

Would it make sense for those of us going to DevDays events which Jeff will be attending to simply include that instead?

For example, I'm going to the London event, and would indeed like a sticker. It would be somewhat silly for Jeff to send it internationally and then come over in person anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Yay, I got mine yesterday! A letter from some "J. Atwood" made it all the way from California to Berlin. Also, on the same day I got my new computer. Me be happy!

Now I have to figure out were to put the stickers...

Comment: be sure to share where you've stuck them here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/stickers-for-stackers-i-e-post-your-sticker-shots :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how many questions and answers we are now going to see for the race to be at the top. I suggest screenshots are made every hour on the hour from now onwards until there are no more.

Comment: Maybe I should sell my one on ebay ;)

Comment: I blame my loosing my first page place today entirely to this creating a hype ;-) Luckily I ordered mine before making place for others to be eligible.

Answer (score 0):

> Beyond that, **any user from the first page of /users can request one by mailing your postal mail address to the email address at the bottom of every page.**

That's worse than the limited edition **Beta** badge.

Comment: hey, it's not our fault you have been wasting your time on stack overflow instead of here