# Change comment vote limit to six every 30 seconds

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, up-votes, rate-limiting

Currently, the comment vote limit is one every five seconds. I suspect it's a common behavior to read a discussion in comments and choose to upvote *more than one comment* after reading *the whole discussion*. This can become a little annoying to wait 5 seconds for every upvote.

Comment: +1 but it will be declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds

Comment: John: I saw that discussion. My proposal *doesn't change* the effective limit so there might be little hope...

Comment: Ralph: I think that's about "commenting" limit. Not voting for comments...

Comment: In poor taste to post a question and an answer with exactly the same content.

Comment: @devinb: my read is blatant rep whoring 'cause Mehrdad wants an MSO sticker.  (He has been over/under the cutoff all day.)  Also, Mehrdad has neither confirmed nor denied this, so let your imagination run wild....200 rep points + two badges...all in a days posting.

Comment: what really annoys me is that I can upvote and unvote 4 questions in 5 seconds, but I can't upvote 2 comments. Aren't votes on Q/A's more important to protect than comments?

Comment: Duplicate: [Can we get x comment votes per x minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-x-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My proposal is to change the limit from **one every five seconds** to something like **six every 30 seconds**. This way, the user experience will improve **without any effective changes** to the current comment vote limit.

Comment: Nice! So I can upvote you twice ;)

Comment: This would make my life so much easier.

Comment: @John Smithers: hehe...I was thinking myself that this it a blatant rep whore ploy to get on the first page (knocking me off) and request an MSO sticker...

Comment: @Stu: I can sell you my one!

Comment: I've already requested mine, so I think I'm in.  But thanks anyway, John.  If denied, I have a case of expired frozen waffles and a half dead pony to trade you.

Comment: TheTXI is only half dead? No sincere job! You can do better!

Comment: There are MSO stickers? Who what where when?

Comment: @devinb: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19857/meta-stack-overflow-stickers-are-here