# What is the reason of not allowing to flag a comment and then delete your own comment in the 5 seconds timeframe?

Tags: support, comments

Suppose I am cleaning the comments of a post; I flag a comment left from another user as obsolete, and I delete the comment I left after that. If I do it in less than 5 seconds, I get the usual warning about the 5 seconds timeframe.

What is the purpose of showing that warning, in that case? As I can only delete my own comments, to which risk would the site exposed, if users were allowed to flag a comment, and delete their own in less than 5 seconds?

Comment: The "mechanical why" is that upvoting, flagging and deleting comments all count as "comment votes," which are limited by general rule to one per five seconds. What you describe is merely a specific (and uncommon) application of the rule. I'll leave the "rationale why" for a team member and a formal answer.

Comment: I know that all the actions are counted as "comment votes"; that is why the dialog box always says that you are allowed to vote on comments every 5 seconds. What I am asking is why the same is applied for an action I can do only on my own comments. If I could vote to delete comments lefts from other users, then I would understand the action is limited to one closing vote every 5 seconds.

Comment: Related: [Comment deletion and upvoting should not use the same rate limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87758/comment-deletion-and-upvoting-should-not-use-the-same-rate-limit)