# Deleting your comment appears to trigger the 5-second rule

Tags: bug, comments, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)

After I submitted a comment to a question I discovered a couple of other comments had been posted before mine. One of those made much the same point so I deleted my comment and tried to upvote the other. When I tried to upvote I got the message "You can only upvote a comment every 5 seconds" or something to that effect.

I don't think deleting my own comment should trigger the 5-second timer.

Comment: I've always found that a bit odd as well, but not odd enough to worry about it. I usually count to five and try again.