# Stickers for Stackers (i.e. post your sticker shots!)

Tags: discussion, stickers

### UPDATE: For those feeling left out of the sticker party, details on how to obtain stickers are [now on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/)!

Look what arrived in the mail yesterday - **stickers!** Thanks Jeff! [image: smiley]

[image][image]

First, I put a StackOverflow on my black 2007 MacBook, my primary computer and the one I use to code and check StackOverflow:

[image: SO sticker in bottom left corner of MacBook]

Second, I put a ServerFault sticker on my home media server, a PowerMac G4 running Mac OS X 10.5, 3 200GB drives connected with ZFS. I know that technically I purchased the machine (and therefore questions about it are ineligible for ServerFault) but it's the closest thing I have:

[image]

I also stuck a SuperUser sticker on my rock-solid WRT54G router running the Tomato firmware:

[image]

To show others I'm living the StackOverflow lifestyle, I also put a SO sticker on my car, a 2005 Nissan Sentra. It's too small to be read by the driver behind me, but it should be visible to those that are walking by my parked vehicle:

[image]

Finally, in the spirit of [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about), I affixed a StackOverflow sticker to my Old Town kayak. It may not make me a [programmer out at sea](http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/), but being a programmer on a lake is good enough for me.

[image]

I still have a few stickers left - **any ideas for other places I could put them?** (I tried my iPhone, but the stickers are too long). And to those that have stickers of your own, **please post some pics of where you've put yours!**

**EDIT:** Just got my [Meta sticker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/we-need-a-meta-sticker) - thanks again, Jeff! I'm not sure if I'm going to actually adhere it to anything considering I only have 1 and the supply is somewhat limited, but it's still cool to have!

[image]

Comment: **I want one!**

Comment: You apparently are the only Kyle Cronin in the world. No need for even an address on the envelope. Super cool.

Comment: @random: I don't know how to put this, but I'm kind of a big deal. People know me. I'm very important.

Comment: Everybody knows Kyle.

Comment: Even when he went by the handle _nobody, people knew who it was.  He's *that* big a deal.

Comment: +1 for boat programming.

Comment: I just realized what a missed opportunity this was to promote the sites using the stickers. None of the stickers have ".com" after the name, so anyone that isn't familiar with the site won't know its a web site.

Comment: It's a good job that's your home media server.  Some of the places I've worked if you put that sticker on one of the machines, you'd come in the next day to find out that somebody had disposed of it because you labelled it as a faulty server.

Comment: I give the one on your car two weeks.  Shame they don't have window clings or at least plastic-based stickers rather than paper.

Comment: @Joel It's managed to stay on so far, even with the snow/rain we've had this winter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn another update: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/stickers-for-stackers-i-e-post-your-sticker-shots/110078#110078

Comment: @Kyle - do you wash that car? ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes, probably every six weeks or so (whenever it's dirty enough for me to stop putting it off). the stickers really are that good

Answer (score 20):

I like how I'm in my 20s and all I can think right now is "Awww I want stickers! :("

Nice kayak btw.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never really been into stickers all that much myself, but I've found them surprisingly addictive.

Comment: No, *this* is a cool kayak: http://gallery.xcski.com/main.php?g2_view=core:ShowItem&g2_itemId=28741

Comment: I'm 35 and thinking about buying a sticker album to save them in.  How sad is that? :)

Comment: Also, you're a better man than I. I promptly destroyed my WRT54G after replacing it with a WRT54GL. I didn't know reliable firmware existed for that piece of junk. (Note the contention here.)

Comment: I also have a WRT54G working happily still after about 2 years.

Comment: It must have come out like a month after I bought my GL because I remember looking for firmware... or I was just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: @Diago: My WRT54G is now five years old, still works great.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Comment: Looks like a toaster behind that ferry.

Comment: you aren't the first one to think so! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toaster_building :)

Comment: My next trip to Circular Quay I expect to see that sticker still there!

Answer (score 10):

Ah, stickers... My wife is looking at me funny now, 'cause some guy named "Jeff" sent me a big pile of 'em.

Oh well. Time to revisit [the origins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001282.html):

[meta is... plushies?! http://shog9.com/metaplushies.png](http://shog9.com/murder.png) (warning: graphics!)

Comment: Where's the flag for "Too awesome"?

Comment: @jjnguy: I agree, it's a little too graphic for a thread about sticker pictures.

Comment: *sigh*... Well, it's your question. How's this?

Comment: Much better, thanks - your original picture was just a little too much

Comment: What's to the left of pinky?

Comment: @random: I cropped the picture *for a reason*.

Comment: The first shot was much better! Now I'm thinking about rolling this back...

Answer (score 7):

[image: Co-Worker Envy]
co-worker envy

I'm going to stick 1 of each on my laptop, but this is the glamor shot for work.  I'm leaving all but the Meta here.

**Edit**: For those unaware, yes the correct address is [*Sir Tom Ritter*](https://ritter.vg/misc/stuff/nameplate.jpg), but I generally don't use it.  The nameplates were ordered for us from our corporate paperwork.  I collected the other nameplates from various co-workers who lost bets (and their souls).

Comment: *Sir* Tom Ritter?

Comment: If anyone cares: "Ritter" is German for "Knight", just FYI

Comment: @balpha Yup.  See, I'm not making up stuff!  I even bought this poster: http://thumbs.filmstarts.de/menu/DieRueckkehrDerJedi-Poster2.jpg

Comment: + 1 for not being Darth Ritter

Answer (score 7):

(moved from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19857/meta-stack-overflow-stickers-are-here) - seems a better fit) I've got mine; I'm still trying to figure out the best uses though, before I waste them... as I mentioned [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/09/stickers-now-what-to-do-with-them.html), so far I'm up to:

- geek plasters ([band-aid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-Aid) if that doesn’t translate).
- laptop chassis emergenccy repair kit (for those annoying cracks, dings, etc)
- repair kit for "Inflatable Annie"
- user-group fodder

And the evidence (the image [may be familiar](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/)):

[image: my table adorned with vinyl]

Comment: You could also put them on shirts or bags - instant schwag!

Comment: I'm not sure shirts would work so well after a wash or two, but the laptop bag may indeed get one...

Comment: Who said anything about washing? ;-)

Comment: Exactly, the only thing you would ever wash is your keyboard.

Comment: @Kyle: Isn't that kind of like rebooting your clothes?

Answer (score 6):

The stickers just arrived, so I put one on my MacBookPro.

I originally linked to a Facebook location, but I don't trust that not to move, so here it is hosted on my server (which does not have a sticker on it yet): http://gallery.xcski.com/d/29025-2/CIMG0016.jpg

Comment: love the airplanes!

Answer (score 6):

For some reason i thought the stickers were bigger than they are...

[image: stickers cash]

Comment: Yeah me too, until I saw this post.  I almost bought a box of large envelopes, but now I know it's okay to just use the small ones I already have.

Answer (score 5):

Arrived today. Thanks :)

(and yes, things are always grainy and out of focus in iceland)

[alt text http://cznp.com/images/DSC00175.JPG](http://cznp.com/images/DSC00175.JPG)

Answer (score 5):

My wife was kind enough to [tweet](http://twitter.com/Hon3yZA/status/4026820738) me when the stickers arrived in the mail today.

My Mac will definitly get one or two, and my wife already recieved her part of the pile. Will update with photos once distrubuted.

Comment: One is missing!

Comment: Is you wife active here, too?

Comment: @balpha - Nope. She asks me all her questions.

Comment: @John - I think Jeff sent these before the Meta stickers arrived.

Comment: Your customs delay stuff really long ;)

Answer (score 5):

I got my **Trilogy Stickers** (**League of Justice Stickers**) three days ago, I immediately took a shot. Stickers are cool and now I will paste them on my car, computer and router. Once I done with that, I will post some more pictures.

[image: Programming360 :: Trilogy Stickers for Stackers]

Answer (score 5):

**ImageShack was reusing the image URL for advertising so the images have been removed.**

Thanks to Tom Ritter for giving me some stickers!

Comment: how can you not have stickers? weren't you on page 1 *somewhere*? If you didn't get any, email me and I will send you some.

Answer (score 4):

So I've had the Stack Overflow sticker on my car for the past 2 years, and it's held up surprisingly well. Here's a pic I took a few days ago:

[image]

It's been discolored a little bit, but the adhesive itself has remained firmly attached to the glass. For the first year the car was parked outside, though it is now parked in a garage (open sides, but under a roof) which mitigates some of the effect of rain and snow, and reduces the need to scrape the window in the winter, which might have otherwise led to accidentally scraping off the sticker.

Still, the sticker is in surprisingly good shape. It's still not great for sticking on cars as it's so small, but if you do decide to at least it'll last a while.

**edit:** After many years of faithful service I'm selling this car. Here is a current photo:

[image]

The sticker's held on remarkably well given that it was applied over 4.5 years ago, but there has been quite a bit of fading.

Comment: I am also thinking to put mine on my car, thanks for sharing that the sticker is still good after 2 years because I was wondering about the quality of the stickers.

Comment: 4+1/2 years? Wow. That's quality.

Comment: damn I was just browsing through all these posts and this is almost getting me emotional

Answer (score 3):

Mine arrived today (in the UK) in a nice hand written envelope - thanks Jeff. I must admit I wasn't expecting the other stickers.

Just got to find somewhere suitable (and relatively durable) to stick them now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine. I am from Malaysia. Got it today. The envelope was already opened when it arrived on my mailbox (I am guessing the local mail staffs opened it grrr)... there are just 2 stickers inside. A Stack Overflow and a Stack Exchange. Good enough for me. But, I don't know why there is a fake Unicorn USD $1000000 bill in there though.

Pic:

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you order those stickers? Unicorn is part of the Meta humor, you can read all about unicorns [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) most likely it's a personal prank of the person in charge of sending the stickers, no harm done in my opinion.

Comment: I found [this chat post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/635419#635419) mentioning this, you can always join [the tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ask there, usually there are team members online who can answer such question in real time.

Comment: I ordered it via a SASE method with a USD1 bill inside. I've had the USD1 bill for many years (a friend gave it to me while i was studying in the UK) and finally got to use it. Ah.. good to know that the 1mil usd note is a prank... and not some other mysterious thing.. lol.

Comment: They probably really liked your $1 bill. :) Did you try asking in the chat?

Comment: I asked, and someone gave a link to the whole story. :)

Comment: Care to share? :-)

Comment: Sure. Here it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow :P

Comment: Can we still order for stack stickers? I mean using this method : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/ ?

Comment: I don't see why not. The SASE method worked for me. Happy with my SO stickers!

Answer (score 2):

I finally got mine (silly air mail). It was the oddest mail-pickup ever. I was walking to pick the mail up, which is quite a distance away from my house, so I was listening the SO podcast. I noticed a letter addressed to me, and, out of the corner of my eye, I notice "Jeff Atwood" up in the corner for the return address. Just a little bit spooky (considering this was the first time in a month I have listened to the podcasts).

[image]

I wanted to put one on the back of my iPod touch, but the stickers are too long :/

Comment: wah? You got a letter too?

Comment: Of course! :P http://superuser.com/users

Comment: Well, yes, you're on the first column on SU, but didn't realise after the Meta call out there would be letters.

Comment: We deserve a letter too!  Got mine this morning :)

Comment: So… why didnt others get a letter? What was this 'meta call out'?