# Removing broken images in locked posts

Tags: support, images, locked

This is tangentally related to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/299072), but the gist of that post is that older ImageShack links are breaking and turning into advertisements. To guard against this, I was editing some posts that I found using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340417/posts-with-images-hosted-on-imageshack-and-10-score) (though a search could also provide examples).

However [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569/resize-transparent-images-using-c-sharp/30593#30593) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103/css-make-divs-align-horizontally) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read/99852#99852) [legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196840/drop-down-list-with-wpf-menu-controls/196873#196873) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111543/tortoisesvn-error-options-of-https-could-not-connect-to-server) that won't allow me to touch them. Most seem to be ads now (though not all), however as far as I can see these are posts that require a moderator's time. Though even at that I'm unable to flag them (hence writing this post instead) so my only way to highlight was by posting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators can edit locked posts, so you if you can bring the post to our attention - **clearly** explaining what the problem is then we'll be able to sort it.

Normally I'd say raise a flag, but you're not able to to flag a  post because it has an historical lock. In this case either see if a moderator is online in chat (you'd need to be lucky) or raise a question on the site's child meta.

As you point out there is a current issue with Image Shack hosted images, here's hoping that there's a more universal solution forthcoming.

Comment: I don't think I was careful enough choosing the correct examples to link here, but at least a few of these posts didn't even give me the option to flag as such (possibly related to my reputation level?).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - you should have enough rep to flag. I honestly can't remember whether you can flag locked posts or not.

Comment: I can flag normally but not locked posts.

Comment: We can flag when the post got "ordinary" lock, but not when there is historical lock. /cc Chris