# Can I search for questions with images?

Tags: support, search

Is there some way to search for questions with images?

People who are too lazy to type their problem often just make a picture of their book or source. This is bad since that doesn't show up when searching. Furthermore we now have [the problem with ImageShack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising), which definitely needs editor's attention to fix.

I'd like to fix some of these questions (Yes, I'll be careful to not flood the active questions list).

But then I have to know what questions contain images. So can I search for questions with images? If so, how?

Comment: *Furthermore we now have the problem with ImageShark.* huh?

Comment: @Won't Images turning into ads. I mistyped it, but HackerKarma just fixed it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising

Comment: @Shadow A support question closed as a duplicate of feature request prevents people from posting solutions (workarounds) as answers.

Comment: @Norm workarounds can be also posted in the feature request itself, it's quite common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a Data Explorer query for this. For example, [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/362497/) which returns questions with images sorted by view count. It also includes other data that may help prioritize editing.