# Trustworthiness of proposed links?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, security, malicious-links

If a question is asked and someone proposes a link to some executable etc. as a solution to the question, has there been a case that malware was being suggested (perhaps unknowingly too)?
Is there a review process of the answers? Is it the responsibility of the OP on what they will do with the answer provided?

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, a fairly closely related question is [What if a user has shared a potential virus?](/q/256995/562482), and a couple of somewhat related questions are [Should this answer be deleted due to linking to (potentially) malicious content](/q/101318/562482) and [A suggested edit cuts out allegedly malicious links. How do I safely check that claim and what review action do I take?](/q/328245/562482).

Comment: An answer which *requires* the reader to go to another page in order to get the *actual* answer, even another Stack Exchange page, is, by definition, Not an Answer (NAA) and should be flagged as "Not an Answer". Note: a question which is asking for pointers to resources is answered by giving a pointer to a resource, so don't confuse those for non-answers. Such questions are off-topic on some/many SE sites, but the answers are actual answers to the question which was asked, so shouldn't be flagged as NAA.

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380796/should-there-be-a-warning-before-users-leave-a-stack-exchange-site/380803#380803

Answer (score 8):

Well generally - there's no review process, and even if a link was fine when it was posted, sometimes domains get squatted, good companies go bad and so on.

If you find a link that's rotted to maliciousness, feel free to flag (for moderator attention). In some cases, editing it to point at an archived version may be appropriate, deleting would be in others.

Ideally the OP keeps it up to date, but failing which the community can help to keep these things curated.

Comment: But how can one know that the link is harmless? E.g. if someone shares an executable that seems legit, I am still not sure how can I verify it.

Comment: the same way you would any other link on the internet I guess, anti-virus, doing some research...

Comment: @Jim Start by looking at the URL. For example, if the answer to a question is something like, "You need to update your IDE for that, download it here", then one would expect the link to be at the official source for that IDE. Someone telling you to download VS Code from [a random string of letters and numbers].com is lying.